# Building an entity join LINQ query

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have the following table strutucture and am accessing them by using MySQL Entity Framework:

```
Table Users
- Id
- Name

Table Subscriptions
- Id
- Id_User
- Id_Course

Table Courses
- Id
- Name
```

What I would like and am having a hard time to do so is building a link query for all users that returns a list with each entry containing:

- User Id;
- User name;
- Concat string separated by comma with all courses for the user or 'no courses' string if none.

This list should be filtered by a part of users name.

I've started to build the code but can't finish it:

```
var Model db = new Model();
var list = from user in db.Users
           join ???
       where user.Name.Contains(filter.Trim())  
       select new { Name = user.Name, Id = user.Id, ???}
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use navigation properties (like `User.Subscriptions`) for this. Depending on how you created the model they may already be there, else you first should add them.

```cs
var query = from u in db.Users
            where user.Name.Contains(filter) // trim the filter value first
            select new
            {
                u.Name,
                u.Id,
                Courses = u.Subscriptions.Select(s => s.Course.Name)
            };

var result = query.AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(q => new
                            {
                                q.Name,
                                q.Id
                                Courses = string.Join(", ", q.Courses)
                            };
```

The reason for doing this in two phases is that `string.Join` can't directly be used in an EF LINQ expression (can't be turned into SQL) so it must be done in memory (i.e. after an `AsEnumerable`).

But still it may be efficient to do a projection first (the first part), otherwise too much data may be fetched from the database.

Comment: Awesome, I had a navigation and your code worked nicely. Entity is so smart that sometimes I don't see how simple it is. Thanks!